# can't handle keyboard events android

Tags: android

I am trying to handle the back button event on my app but its not working at all. I have inplemented ActivityGroup in my app according to the post [Android: TabActivity Nested Activities](http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/)

I have added the following code according to many posts in this website

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed: " + keyCode);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

but for some reason i still dont know i am not getting the lines to be logged, it goes back to the home screen. I know that the onBackPressed will not work for me because I need to have this app implemented using api level 4 and it is not available at this level.

My ActivityGroup has only two activities, one list view and a details view. I have put this code on all the three classes to try something different, but still cant get it working. I see "No keyboard for id 0" in the logs, but i dont think it means something that can be related to the problem.

I do appreciate any answer to this.
Many thanks
T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a log statement right above the return line and see what KeyEvent is happening.

like this:

```
Log.w(keyCode, "This is the key code that is returned");
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

Now look at the returned value and verify/compare it to `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` and this may point you in the direction of your problem.

Comment: I figured out what was going on. I didnt know that this method should be implemented on the class that implements the Tab and not actually on each activity opened inside the tab content. Need to understand why, will do a research later. Thanks for you reply.